# Unable to locate installable unit

Tags: eclipse, git, target, platform

I'm using Eclipse Luna and as I'm working on two different computers, I wanted to install the project I'm working on on my new laptop. 
I downloaded the git-repositories needed and wanted to set the target platform before starting to implement.
But when I click on luna.target, the resolving target platform fails and every locations shows up "Unable to locate installable unit".

As I do some research in the WWW, I found that it's probably a bug in eclipse and can be resolved by restarting/updating/cleaning the project...
But all of these steps didn't work for me.

The locations themselves should be right, because resolving the target platform on my first computer always works.

I'm desperate, please help me! Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: This question is strongly related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547007/eclipse-unable-locate-installable-unit).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your luna.target there are local file path that are only available on your first computer. Where did you get the target from?

Try to inspect the luna.target file with a text editor (it's XML) to see which path and URLs are used inside the target definition.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I looked through the target file but couldn't found any pathes related to my computer. all targets I use are https (for example: http://download.eclipse.org/cbi/updates/license) I also tried to install a second workspace on the first computer, but this doesn't work either...